# How do I interactively type \r\n-terminated query in netcat?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, netcat, newlines

```
$ nc example.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

It works, line separator is just `0A` here instead of required `0D0A`.

How do I type a `0D0A`-separated query in netcat?

It is easy to do one-time thing with `printf` manually typing `\r\n` each time or to implement some `todos`-like Perl oneliner and pipe it to `nc`, but maybe there is some easy way I miss?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

My `netcat` has an option `-C` or `--crlf` to replace `\n` by `\r\n` on stdin.

Alternatively, it depends on what terminal you are using. My default settings can be seen by:

```
$ stty -a
... lnext = ^V; ...
```

This shows the **literal-next** character for input is <kbd>control-V</kbd>.  So typing <kbd>control-v</kbd> followed by <kbd>control-m</kbd> will insert a carriage-return (as opposed to a newline, which is what you get when you hit the `return` or `enter` key).

Comment: Nice find, didn't know about `-C`.

Comment: What about sending any byte interactively through netcat, e.g. `0x01`, `0x02`, etc. Is it possible?.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to be supported on GNU Netcat

Comment: @CodeBling You can also try socat if you have that: `socat READLINE TCP4:example.com:80,crnl`

Comment: @meuh good call

Answer (score 4):

You can pipe a string to `nc`:

```
echo -ne 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n' | nc example.com 80
```

Check with:

```
$ echo -ne 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n' | hd
00000000  47 45 54 20 2f 20 48 54  54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a  |GET / HTTP/1.1..|
00000010  48 6f 73 74 3a 20 65 78  61 6d 70 6c 65 2e 63 6f  |Host: example.co|
00000020  6d 0d 0a 0d 0a                                    |m....|
00000025
```

Comment: How do I do this interactively, entering another request after I see the reply?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe `sed` to `nc` in unbuffered mode (`-u`) to convert the `\n` from your stdin to `\r\n`:

```
sed -u 's/$/\r/g' | nc localhost 6379
```

You can also use `unix2dos` with `stdbuf`:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 unix2dos | nc localhost 6379
```